# Pandas code running but not doing anything

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

dataset=pd.read_excel('file_path')

sia=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

dataset['polarity scores']=dataset['column_title'].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(str(x))['compound'])

print("done")
```

I would like it to take the excel file named/located file_path and give me polarity scores for the text in the column entitled column title but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.The code runs without any errors but it does not edit the excel file at all

Comment: I think you need to call `dataset.to_excel('new_output.xlsx')` to save your changes to a new file. you can also overwrite your existing file, but be careful!

Comment: Also, if you are in jupyter notebooks, you can just write `dataset ` to view your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save your file

use `dataset.to_excel('output_file_path.xlsx')` to save your file

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

dataset=pd.read_excel('file_path')

sia=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

dataset['polarity scores']=dataset['column_title'].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(str(x))['compound'])

dataset.to_excel('output_file_path.xlsx', index = False) # save file

print("done")
```